# Definition of space $\mathcal{D}^{1,2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

My question is the regular definition of the space $\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\Omega)$,  for some open $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

I know this space is usefull for the studies of solution for PDE problems. I jus't found some equivalences around the books.

Sorry for the weak question, but I can't found this in bibliography.
Every help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe this is standard notation or at least I'm unfamiliar with it. Where did you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and $1 \le p < \infty$ we often define $\mathcal{D}^{m,p}(\Omega)$ for the space obtained by taking the completion of $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) = C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ relative to the norm
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{\mathcal{D}^{m,p}} = \left(\sum_{|\alpha| = m} \Vert \partial^\alpha u \Vert_{L^p}^p \right)^{1/p}. 
$$
Note crucially that we only look at the $m^{th}$ order derivatives, but this does define a norm on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ due to the compact support condition.  The $\mathcal{D}$ part of the notation comes from the connection to distributions, where $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}'$ are used frequently.

Comment: This spaces have a name? And more, is it between $W^{m,p}$ and $L^P$?

Comment: The norm should be equivalent to the $W^{m,p}$ norm.

Comment: This I don't understand. The norm are equivalents, but why the spaces are different?  What makes a functions belongs to $W^{m,p}$ or $\mathcal{D}^{m,p}?$

Comment: @daw If the domain is bounded, then lower order norms can be controlled via Poincare inequalities.  However, if $\Omega$ is not bounded, say $\mathbb{R}^n$, then this is no longer true.  A simple scaling argument shows that this norm can't control the $L^p$ norm when $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$.  Depending on the values of $m$ and $p$ the resulting completion may not even consist of functions.

Comment: Then what is the definition in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example?

Comment: This is the definition in all cases.  It does not always give you a space equivalent to $W^{m,p}$ or $W^{m,p}_0$.  Hence the different notation.

Comment: Thanks @Glitch, helped so much!